# Files uploaded to Artifactory are of correct length but the content is full of zeroes

Tags: maven, artifactory

I have setup the recent version of the open-source Artifactory on my Ubuntu server with mGinx fronting it, and everything looks great! On the first attempt to upload a file to a repository I have got strange result though.

I have done PUT to the following URL (which is my Artifactory instance) "http://artifactory.my.domain_name/artifactory/list/my-repository/servlet-api-2.5.jar" with the body of the "jar" file and content-type of "application/binary".

The response received back is "All good". When the file is downloaded back from the repository it is of a correct size, but it has zeroes (0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00...) instead of the original content.

I tried different files - same result for any. Tried to do it via "curl" and via "HttpRequester" plugin in Firefox - same outcome each time.

Any ideas on what may be wrong with it are very much appreciated!

Comment: Might be related to nginx configuration. Have you tried uploading directly to Artifactory?

Comment: I have the same suspicion. Have not tested this hypothesis yet, but I do have other projects behind the same nGinx and some of them have file upload that works fine. nGinx configuration for Artifactory in my case is very simple. It does not have the complexity that would create a lot of room for variation.

Comment: can you share an example of how you uploaded using curl? did you try uploading using the UI?

Comment: Hi Dror, thank you for coming back to me on this! I have just re-tried the uploading of the same file using the same method as previously, which is HttpRequestor plugin for Firefox (UI as you suggested). This time I have bypassed the nGinx sending the file directly to Artifactory and this time it worked Ok. You were right - it was nGinx after all. Good news in my case - I can afford to bypass nGinx for uploads. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a problem with nGinx, which passes '0x00' bytes instead of the actual content of posted data to Artifactory. It has been confirmed by sending the file directly to Artifactory bypassing nGinx, which resulted in correct file content being saved in repository.

Comment: If you can share your NginX setup, someone might be able to find the issue. I assume it is a matter of configuration. BTW, you can use the Artifactory [Reverse Proxy Configuration Generator](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+a+Reverse+Proxy) to generate you NginX configuration.